# Visual Studio 2008 custom config xsd intellisense auto complete broken!

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, validation, xsd, autocomplete

I used to use the intellisense feature within visual studio 2003 for editing a custom .config file against my custom xsd schema.

I put the schema in:

Common7\Packages\schemas\xml

Everything worked happily, no problem.

I have just tried to do the same in VS 2008 and there is no intellisense. The schema viewer for the .config file in the properties windows says that my custom schema is loaded and everything should work but when I try nothing is suggested.

There seem to other problems related to XAML intellisense but none of these solutions worked for me.

Stuck and frustrated! Anyone else had this before or know of something that has changed in 2008?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

For general xml type intellisense I think you need to put the xsd in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas (or C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Xml\Schemas)

For XAML intellisense, I've had mixed results and sometimes the results vary depending on how long I've had Studio open for - I'm praying 2010 has much improved support.

Comment: You don't need to mess with program files directories. Just add the XSD to your solution... anywhere, and whatever my_namespace is in `<xs:schema targetNamespace="my_namespace">`, just assign that as the xmlns attribute of your custom section when you place it in the web.config file.  If your custom section is named 'my_section', then you'd open it with `<my_section xmlns="my_namespace">`. In fact, as you're typing xmlns=, when you press the quote key, you should get a list of all the built-in namespaces, along with the my_namespace as defined in the xsd document you included in your solution.